# Cursor returning Max 2 rows

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, android-activity, cursor

I'm doing a check in order to get my favorite own Promotions objects into an array. I tried to do this (from my PromotionsBDD class which controls my Table Promotions from my SQLite Database):

```
public ArrayList<Promotion> getListPromotionsFavorites()
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {"ID", "RATING", "TITLE", "COMPANY_ID","AVAILABLEDATE", "DESCRIPTION", "SETONFAVORITE"};

        Cursor objCursor = bdd.query(TABLE_PROMOTIONS, columns,"SETONFAVORITE = ?",new String[]{"true"},null,null,null,null);

        int id = objCursor.getColumnIndex("ID");
        int rating = objCursor.getColumnIndex("RATING");
        int title = objCursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE");
        int companyid = objCursor.getColumnIndex("COMPANY_ID");
        int availabledate = objCursor.getColumnIndex("AVAILABLEDATE");
        int description = objCursor.getColumnIndex("DESCRIPTION");
        int setonfavorite = objCursor.getColumnIndex("SETONFAVORITE");

        ArrayList<Promotion> promoFavoriteArray = new ArrayList<Promotion>();
        objCursor.moveToFirst();// position sur la première ligne

        if (objCursor != null) 
        {
            if (objCursor.isFirst())
            {
                do 
                {
                    String resultid = objCursor.getString(id);
                    String resultrating = objCursor.getString(rating);
                    String resultitle = objCursor.getString(title);
                    int resultcompanyid = objCursor.getInt(companyid);
                    String resultavailbledate = objCursor.getString(availabledate);
                    String resultdescription = objCursor.getString(description);
                    String resultsetonfavorite = objCursor.getString(setonfavorite);

                    Promotion promo = new Promotion(resultid, resultrating, resultitle, resultcompanyid,resultavailbledate,resultdescription, resultsetonfavorite);
                    promoFavoriteArray.add(promo);
                    objCursor.moveToNext();//positionnement sur le suivant
                }
                while(objCursor.isLast());
            }
        }
        objCursor.deactivate();
        objCursor.close();
    return promoFavoriteArray;
}
```

It working fine using 1 or 2 entries for my promoFavoriteArray, but i put 3 entries into this array,it returns an array of 1 until 3..

EDIT: i tried this:

```
ArrayList<Promotion> promoFavoriteArray = new ArrayList<Promotion>();
            objCursor.moveToFirst();
            if(objCursor != null)
            {
                do 
                {
                        String resultid = objCursor.getString(id);
                        String resultrating = objCursor.getString(rating);
                        String resultitle = objCursor.getString(title);
                        int resultcompanyid = objCursor.getInt(companyid);
                        String resultavailbledate = objCursor.getString(availabledate);
                        String resultdescription = objCursor.getString(description);
                        String resultsetonfavorite = objCursor.getString(setonfavorite);

                        Promotion promo = new Promotion(resultid, resultrating, resultitle, resultcompanyid,resultavailbledate,resultdescription, resultsetonfavorite);
                        promoFavoriteArray.add(promo);
                        objCursor.moveToNext();//positionnement sur le suivant
                }
                while(!objCursor.isLast());
            }
        objCursor.deactivate();
        objCursor.close();
        return promoFavoriteArray;
```

but I got CursorIndexOutOfBoundException..

Answer (score 0):

You're doing (pseudocode):

```
first
        add(current)
        next
    repeat if last
```

If there's 2 items, after you add, next makes it's index 2, you loop and add again.  You have two items, great.

If there's 3 items you add once, it's not last so it doesn't loop again.  You end up with one.

Instead, try something like (you don't need the isFirst check and you need while *not* last):

```
if (objCursor == null)
    return array; // empty

objCursor.moveToFirst();
do
{
    // read data
    array.Add(promo);

} while (!objCursor.isLast())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to perform this :

```
ArrayList<Promotion> promoFavoriteArray = new ArrayList<Promotion>();
        boolean hasMore = objCursor.moveToFirst();

        while(hasMore)
        {
                String resultid = objCursor.getString(id);
                String resultrating = objCursor.getString(rating);
                String resultitle = objCursor.getString(title);
                int resultcompanyid = objCursor.getInt(companyid);
                String resultavailbledate = objCursor.getString(availabledate);
                String resultdescription = objCursor.getString(description);
                String resultsetonfavorite = objCursor.getString(setonfavorite);

                Promotion promo = new Promotion(resultid, resultrating, resultitle, resultcompanyid,resultavailbledate,
                        resultdescription, resultsetonfavorite);
                promoFavoriteArray.add(promo);
                hasMore = objCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    objCursor.deactivate();
    objCursor.close();
    return promoFavoriteArray;
```